# Pgfplots rounded corners and plot problem

Tags: pgfplots, rounded-corners

I noticed something strange recently when trying to use `rounded corners` in pgfplots: it totally ruins the plot. See below without rounded corners:

[image]

and then with rounded corners:

[image]

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,trim axis left, trim axis right]
\tikzset{every mark/.append style={scale=0.6}}
\pgfplotsset{legend style={font=\footnotesize}}

\begin{axis}[   grid=both,
            rounded corners,
            ]
    \addplot[samples=100,color=blue,very thick,smooth,domain=-10:10] {cos(x^(3))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for your ideas !

Comment: Why do you want to use rounded corners? Just to make the axis lines rounded corners?

Comment: I just want the surrounding box to be rounded, I'm not sure to understand what you mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only want the axis lines to be rounded, you need to set the `axis line style` key. Otherwise, `pgfplots` applies the `rounded corners` style to all of the lines it draws, including the plots.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,trim axis left, trim axis right]
\tikzset{every mark/.append style={scale=0.6}}
\pgfplotsset{legend style={font=\footnotesize}}

\begin{axis}[   grid=both,
            axis line style={rounded corners},
            ]
    \addplot[samples=100,color=blue,very thick,smooth,domain=-10:10] {cos(x^(3))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could this be done within the axis environment? I am able to add a frame by typing the word \begin{axis}[frame,]\end{axis}. Is there a way to make that frame have rounded corners?