# Pgfplots rounded corners and plot problem - part II

Tags: pgfplots, rounded-corners

This is a follow-up to question [Pgfplots rounded corners and plot problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232725/pgfplots-rounded-corners-and-plot-problem).

When the grid is right on the edge of the plot, it does not bend with the axes. Is it possible to apply bending to the grid too ?

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,trim axis left, trim axis right]
\tikzset{every mark/.append style={scale=0.6}}
\pgfplotsset{legend style={font=\footnotesize}}

\begin{axis}[   grid=both,xmin=-10,xmax=10,ymin=-1,ymax=1,
        axis line style={rounded corners},
        ]
\addplot[samples=100,color=blue,very thick,smooth,domain=-10:10] {cos(x^(3))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Cheers

Comment: Can you please post the code that you use to generate the image? Thanks.

Comment: I edited the question. Thanks for your interest

Comment: Ideas anyone ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you think the ticks should be "bended"? I think you mean with this that they should *move* to the "inner part" of the axis, but this is not (easily) possible I think.

Here I present two solutions without "bending" the ticks. For more details have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
            % define some macros that hold the min and max values for the axes ...
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\xmin}{-10}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\xmax}{10}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\ymin}{-1}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\ymax}{1}
        \begin{axis}[
            % and apply the values here
            xmin=\xmin,
            xmax=\xmax,
            ymin=\ymin,
            ymax=\ymax,
            grid=both,
            axis line style={rounded corners},    % = rounded corners=4pt
            % -----
            % activate the `set layers' feature to be sure that the extra
            % ticks are drawn below the axis lines
            set layers,
            % then add extra ticks in the four corners
            % (unfortunately `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}' and friends
            %  can't be used in the axis options, so you have to provide the
            %  values manually or you have do define commands like I did,
            %  so you only have one place if you want to change the values)
            extra x ticks={\xmin,\xmax},
            extra y ticks={\ymin,\ymax},
            % and finally set the extra tick style to draw thick white lines
            % ("thick" because the grid lines are drawn thick by default)
            % (of course this means that you will see the white lines,
            %  if you change the background color!)
            extra tick style={
                grid=none,
                tick style={
                    draw=white,
                    thick,
                },
            },
            % -----
%            % alternatively just enlarge the limits a bit, so the ticks
%            % are outside of the "rounded corners part"
%            % (the default value of `rounded corners' is 4pt)
%            enlargelimits={abs=4pt},
            % -----
        ]
            \addplot [
                samples=100,
                color=blue,
                very thick,
                smooth,
                domain=-10:10,
            ] {cos(x^(3))};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing a zoomed result of the above code]