# pgfplots: Rounded Corners for Diagram Box

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics

We consider a small code using `pgfplots` where the external grid is rectangular, like this image created with this MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.15}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But this rectangular grid is fixed or is it possible to obtain also a image like this image where the edges are rounded and can be coloured and where you can draw different graphics within the rounded rectangle?

[image]

Comment: Hi! Maybe related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232725 (`axis line style = {rounded corners`). I also proposed a new title of the question. Feel free to reverse my proposal.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Very kinddddddddd :-) perfect but I'd like them more rounded: Edge rounding is ugly with `rounded corners`. If there is not an answer I close my question :-) thank to your link.

Comment: How about a Tikz solution?

Comment: @BlackMild Very kind I wanted created something as my first code in this recent question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526691/spy-tikz-library-an-expansion-of-differents-zoom. If there are other solutions are welcome always for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This uses plain TikZ with `intersections` library for the intersection point. Note that `scope` environment can be nested, several `\clip`s are used for filling. If you want the rectangle with more rounded corners, then simply use `[rounded corners=3mm]` e.g., in the definition of `\bb`.

I believe that `pgfplots` also can be easily drawn this, with suitable options in the `axis` environment. However, plain TikZ makes me more comfortable.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\def\bb{[rounded corners] (-1,-1) rectangle (2,1.5)}
\def\curveA{plot[domain=-1:2,smooth,samples=100]  (\x,{\x/(sqrt(1+\x*\x))})}
\def\curveB{plot[domain=-1:2,smooth,samples=100](\x,{pow(\x,4)-\x})}
\begin{scope} \clip \bb;
\begin{scope} 
\clip \curveA|-cycle;
\clip \curveB--cycle;
\fill[cyan!20] \bb;
\end{scope}
\draw (-1,0)--(2,0) (0,-1)--(0,1.5);
\draw[magenta,thick,name path=A] \curveA;
\draw[cyan,thick,name path=B] \curveB;
\path[name intersections={of=A and B}] (intersection-2) node[cyan,rectangle,minimum size=2mm,draw,thick]{};
\end{scope}
\draw[cyan] \bb;
\foreach \i in {-.5,0,...,1.5} \draw (\i,.05)--(\i,-.05);
\foreach \j in {-.5,0,...,1} \draw (.05,\j)--(-.05,\j);
\path
(-1,0) node[left]{$-1$}
(2,0) node[right]{$2$}
(0,-1) node[below]{$-1$}
(0,1.5) node[above]{$1.5$}
(1.2,-.5) node{$y=x^4-x$}
(.6,1.2) node (N) {$y=\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$};
\draw[-stealth] (N)--+(-60:.6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow also this answer it is very nice. But actually I can not vote because I have finished the votes :-(

Comment: I upvoted for you @sebastiano

Answer (score 9):

All of this can be done with simple `pgfplots` tools.

1. The rounded frame is as simple as `axis background/.style={rounded corners=4mm,draw=blue}`,
2. Getting rid of the arrows as simple as `every inner x axis line/.append style={-},every inner y axis line/.append style={-}`,
3. The shading can be done with `fillbetween`.
4. The formulae are simple labels/pins.
5. The max and min values can be automatically attached on the basis of the `xmin` and so on values with `after end axis/.code`.

For your convenience I collected most of these things in a style called `Sebastiano`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\pgfplotsset{Sebastiano/.style={xticklabel=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,
    axis lines = center,
    every inner x axis line/.append style={-},
    every inner y axis line/.append style={-},
    axis background/.style={rounded corners=4mm,draw=blue},
    before end axis/.code={\path (0,0) coordinate (O);},
    after end axis/.code={
    \path
     (current axis.east|-O) node[right]
      {\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}}}
     (current axis.west|-O) node[left]
      {\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}}}
     (current axis.north-|O) node[above]
      {\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}}}
     (current axis.south-|O) node[below]
      {\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}}};
    }
}}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{axis}[Sebastiano,width =12cm,
    xmin = -1,xmax = 2,
    ymin = -1,ymax = 1.5,
    domain=-1:2,smooth]
    \addplot[name path=A,color=magenta,thick]  {x/sqrt(1+x*x)}
    coordinate[pos=0.7,pin={[black,pin edge={stealth-,thick}]100:{$\displaystyle y=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$}}](pA);
    \addplot[name path=B,color=cyan,thick]  {x^4-x}
    coordinate[pos=0.19,label={[black]below right:{$\displaystyle y=x^4-x$}}](pB);
    \addplot fill between [of=A and B,
        split,
        every segment no 0/.style={fill=none},
        every segment no 1/.style={cyan,opacity=50},
        every segment no 2/.style={fill=none},
        ];
\end{axis}
%
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

For starting point I use Dr. Manuel Kuehner' answer (since it use simpler diagram). With help of the `fit` TikZ library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[name=PLOT,
    width = 80mm,
    height= 60mm,
    xmin = -1.2,
    xmax =  2.2,
    ymin = -1.3,
    ymax =  4.3,
    axis lines = center,
    scale only axis
    ]
    \addplot[
        domain = 0:2,
        red,
        line width = 1pt
        ]
        {x^2};
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\end{axis}
%
\node (f) [draw=blue, thick, rounded corners = 5mm, 
           inner sep=0pt, fit=(PLOT)] {};
\path   (O-|f.west)  node[lbl, left]  {$-1$}  (O-|f.east)  node[lbl,right] {$2$}
        (O|-f.north) node[lbl,above]  {$1.5$} (O|-f.south) node[lbl,below] {$-1$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Edit: added labels of coordinates outside of `f` node (they are `\Large` and `red`, that you easy see, that they are on picture, this settings you can easy change)

[image]

Comment: I can no more vote for this day. I've used all the votes :-) Can you put, please, the labels on the function? But the labels can exit from the rectangle as the 2nd my image?

Comment: +1: very nice (fit)

Comment: Nice, but... `Package pgf Error: No shape named f is known.` Presumably due to [this edit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/526858/revisions)...

Comment: @frougon, ups, you are right. IN answer is not the recent MWE, This is the name node, which fit axis environment. I will correct this asap.

Answer (score 6):

- Just an idea/start (going to  bed now).
- Placing two plots on top of each other.
- They have the same size but different axis options.
- `scale only axis` is important.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{axis}[
    width = 80mm,
    height = 60mm,
    xmin = -1.2,
    xmax = 2.2,
    ymin = -1.3,
    ymax = 4.3,
    axis x line = center,
    axis y line = center,
    %axis line style = {rounded corners = 4mm},
    scale only axis
    ]
    \addplot[
        domain = 0:2, 
        red, 
        line width = 1pt
        ] 
        {x^2};
\end{axis}
%
\begin{axis}[
    width = 80mm,
    height = 60mm,
    xmin = -1.2,
    xmax = 2.2,
    ymin = -1.3,
    ymax = 4.3,
    axis line style = {rounded corners = 5mm, blue},
    scale only axis,
    ticks = none
    ]
\end{axis}
%
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: On the lower left corner, there seems to be a wrong little line. Bug?!

Comment: Very nice, but I hope you appreciate my observation. If you zoom in on the edges, the edge isn't rounded. You have a straight line that extends it too  to the rounding of the edge. I had only, for today, and I give it to you :-)

Comment: @sebastiano that's also my observation, see my previous comment. Maybe a bug? Good night, hopefully you get a better answer.

Comment: You're great. Good night. My upvote there is :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano I opened a bug report on https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/234/.

Comment: Hiiii :-) and welcome...always thank you into my questions and profile :-)

Comment: Bug report update: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/issues/234 (still open as it seems).

Comment: Very kind Dr. Manuel I have seen your old question on github. It is still open.